# seeying objects in viewport shading with cycles engine

Tags: cycles-render-engine

In Viewport Shading in Cycles engine I can't see the colors, light or shadows of the object and I can only see the outline (edge) of the object, i can see it only in EEVEE mode, what should I do?
[image]

Comment: Hello, is there a light? It might be a graphic card bug, try a previous version of the driver? Or please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/